# How can I turn on language dialect "CXX23" in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, visual-studio-2019

C++ Project fails to compile in Visual Studio with this error:

Target "cmTC_55893" requires the language dialect "CXX23" (with compiler
extensions), but CMake does not know the compile flags to use to enable it.

It does compile correctly in QtDesigner, which is using MSVC 2019 x64

Do I need to configure anything in visual studio to turn on the CXX23

Comment: You can't.  Best you can try to do is use `/std:c++latest` which brings in C++20+ features.

Comment: You can use [feature testing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test) to check if a particular C++23 feature is available when you use `/std:c++latest`.

Comment: [msvc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-170) [cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) (note CMake 2.20 is required)

Comment: Note also that to have C++23 you need Visual Studio 2022 not 2019. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 0):

From the [Visual  Studio release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/what-s-new-for-visual-cpp-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-170#whats-new-for-c-in-visual-studio-version-174),  Visual Studio C++23 is being implemented.

> We continue to track the latest developments in C++ standardization.
> Support for these C++23

features is available by including /std:c++latest in your compiler options: